# Connecting to MSSQL server in Spark shell and running a stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

How can I connect to a sql server using jdbc in spark-shell and then query the database using a stored procedure?
I have seen this code:

```
val url =
   "jdbc:mysql://yourIP:yourPort/test?
   user=yourUsername; password=yourPassword"
   val df = sqlContext
   .read
   .format("jdbc")
   .option("url", url)
   .option("dbtable", "people")
   .load()
```

But I need to run a stored procedure.
When I use `exec` command for the `dbtable` option above, it gives me this error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near
>   the keyword 'exec'.

Comment: I have same question :(

Comment: I could not find a way to do that. Then I had to write a java code with spark.